# Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Uno.UI, Version=255.255.255.255

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, uno-platform, windows-community-toolkit

After upgrading Uno.UI to 3.11.6 I'm getting the following error when compiling my project:

Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Uno.UI, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

A quick search on Discord comes up with multiple questions regarding this, with the responses suggesting to bump the Minimal version of the Windows SDK used.
I did that, and have configured both the target and min SDK to the Windows 11 - build 22000 SDK, but I still get this issue.

Apparently, it happens right after I update my Community Toolkit NuGet to 7.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem often occurs when the library does not support your target platform.

Make sure you are using Community Toolkit packages without the `Uno.` prefix for the Uwp project.

`Uno.Microsoft.Toolkit` packages do not support UWP projects since version 7.0.0.

[Here's](https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-community-toolkit.html?tabs=tabid-vswin#referencing-the-windows-community-toolkit-from-a-cross-targeted-library) detailed official documentation about it.

Comment: Here's the related Uno platform documentation: https://platform.uno/docs/articles/uno-community-toolkit.html?tabs=tabid-vswin#referencing-the-windows-community-toolkit-from-a-cross-targeted-library

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone lands here with the same situation that I have just encountered, here is my case: I had the same error when a UWP app that uses a Uno class library had its min target version set to Build 18362. Changing it to Build 19041 solved the problem. I am using Toolkit 7.11.